# What is the equivalent of /etc/apache2/envvars in EL-based systems?

Tags: centos, redhat, apache2, httpd

In Debian-based systems, it's possible to source a bash script in `/etc/apache2/envvars` to dynamically set an environment variable. Here is an example:

- Create a file (`/etc/profile.d/myenv.sh`) with the content `export STARTUP_TIME=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')`.
- Add the line `. /etc/profile.d/myenv.sh` at the end of `/etc/apache2/envvars`.
- Restart apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.
- Create a file (`test.php`) with just `<?php phpinfo();` and load the page in a browser to see the value of the variable `STARTUP_TIME` under "Environment".

There are lots of suggestions to use `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` in EL systems and declare that as `EnvironmentFile` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` to set env vars, but that file is apparently not a script (see https://superuser.com/a/1817160/777045) thus cannot be used to dynamically set variables.